# jquery ajax - click event doubling

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and ajax.

I have a navigation button which I click and it runs some php code.
Problem is each time I click the button, it runs the code more times than the last time.
so click 1: runs code once.
click 2: 2 times
click 3: 4 times
click 4: 8 times!

Here is the jquery code. I don't know if the problem is here or somewhere else.
Thanks in advance..

```
$('#loa_pending_nav').click(
    function() {
        var display_type = "Pending";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'loa_display.php',
            statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                    alert('loa_display.php --> NOT FOUND');
                }
            },
            data: "&display_type="+display_type,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#display').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you show the `HTML` as well

Comment: could you please show the html code? Not just the element with id=loa_pending_nav but also the elements containing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PHP file seems to be a webpage and you're inserting its `<script>` tags into your HTML each time you click the button, causing your problem.

Instead of this:

```
$('#display').html(data);
```

Do this:

```
$(data).find('body').children().appendTo('#display');
```

Comment: Yes, That was it. In my PHP file I was re-loading the same javascript file. After I removed the javascript loading everything worked great , Thanks :)